# Link "likes" on my site to those on my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-application, like

My website has had a Facebook "like" button for some time, and it now has a few hundred likes. I never made a Facebook page until now. I created one today, and it has zero likes

Can I somehow link the existing likes to that Facebook page and vice versa? I would like to make them one and the same.

Comment: It may be code or plugin issue which you are using to put FB like button.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not allow you to link the likes on your site and on your page.   In fact, every page on your site can have a different number of likes.

[Likes cannot be transferred between pages on your site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810291/move-facebook-likes-from-one-url-to-another) or between your home page and your Facebook page.

The only time that likes can be consolidated is if there are two Facebook pages with the same topic.  Then [those two pages can be merged](http://boostlikes.com/blog/2014/01/transfer-facebook-likes-different-page) it will add the likes from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Most likes are related to the current page you are browsing on your site. On the other hand, profile likes are related to your facebook page off your site. You need to make a facebook "profile" like in order to assimilate to your "like count" on the facebook profile. So when you are making the like button, use this as the url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/MyProfileUrl?ref=profile
```

Now when they click like, it will add a like to the profile itself. Every page on your site that displays the like snippet will show the count of likes on your facebook profile.

Obviously if your facebook profile has 0 likes, the button will show 0. Not sure why you would have a facebook like button without creating a facebook profile in the first place...it's just common sense that if a profile doesn't exist there will be no count source right?